# QSimpleScada is not compiling 'class QTextStream' has no member named 'setCodec' SimpleScada

Tags: c++, c, qt, scada

Hi thank you all for your time,
simple scada doesn't want to compile -> empty project or their sample project called Weather https://github.com/IndeemaSoftware/QSimpleScadaSample. I install lib via git and qpm but issues of lack of proper members in classes during the compilation stay the same.
I really appreciate any kind of help because I'm really stuck
Highest Regards

**About QT version**
Qt Creator 5.0.1
Based on Qt 5.15.2 (MSVC 2019, 64 bit)
Built on Sep 14 2021 01:17:14
From revision 7e965629b0

**About compiler's version**
mingw 8.1.0 64

**Error logs**
debug\qscadaboard.o ....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboard.cpp
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQPM_INIT(E)="E.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qrc:/"));" -DQPM_USE_NS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICKWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I../Weather -I. -I../../Qt/libs/vendor -I../../Qt/libs/vendor/com/indeema/qsimplescada -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtQuickWidgets -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtQuick -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtOpenGL -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtQmlModels -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtQml -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtCore -Idebug -I. -I/include -IC:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug\qscadaboardcontroller.o ....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboardcontroller.cpp
....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboardcontroller.cpp: In member function 'void QScadaBoardController::openProject(QString)':
....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboardcontroller.cpp:264:28: error: 'class QTextStream' has no member named 'setCodec'
lStreamFileOut.setCodec("UTF-8");
^~~~~~~~
....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboardcontroller.cpp: In member function 'void QScadaBoardController::saveProject(QString)':
....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboardcontroller.cpp:315:18: error: 'class QTextStream' has no member named 'setCodec'
lOut.setCodec("UTF-8");
^~~~~~~~
....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboard.cpp: In member function 'virtual void QScadaBoard::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)':
....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboard.cpp:112:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QMouseEvent'
if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
^~
In file included from C:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets/QWidget:1,
from ....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard../QScadaObject/qscadaobject.h:6,
from ....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboard.h:4,
from ....\Qt\libs\vendor\com\indeema\qsimplescada\QScadaBoard\qscadaboard.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/6.2.0/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:73:7: note: forward declaration of 'class QMouseEvent'
class QMouseEvent;
^~~~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:2090: debug/qscadaboardcontroller.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:1910: debug/qscadaboard.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/Dokumenty/AiR_rok_4/S7/EngineeringThesis/QSimpleScadaSample-master/build-Weather-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: debug] Error 2
10:09:02: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Weather (kit: Desktop Qt 6.2.0 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make"
10:09:02: Elapsed time: 00:05.

**My Weather.pro file**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-07-24T19:14:55
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network qml quick quickwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

include (E:/Dokumenty/AiR_rok_4/S7/EngineeringThesis/Qt/libs/vendor/vendor.pri)

TARGET = Weather
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact waenter code herernings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES +=

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sCFn.png
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message. What is the version of Qt that you use? Compiler?  What have you changed in the original `*.pro` file?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I added mentioned information to main post's content. Only think I changed was path to file vendor.pi

Answer (score 5):

1. The software you're trying to compile is 2-3 years old.  It must have been written & tested with Qt 5 in mind.
2. The Qt version you're using is 6.2 (this is seen in the error message).
3. In Qt 5, class `QTextStream` has a member function `setCodec`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream-members.html
4. In Qt 6 this member function is gone: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream-members.html

Conclusions:

The simplest solution would be for you to downgrade Qt version to the 5 series. Otherwise you risk being forced to resolve differences between code written for Qt 5 and your Qt 6 library. This may be easy - I don't know. Anyway, Qt 5 is still widely used, in particular, even your brand new  QtCreator was compiled with it.

Some hints on porting Qt 5 applications to Qt 6: https://www.qt.io/blog/porting-from-qt-5-to-qt-6-using-qt5compat-library

According to the blog behind the link, `QTextCodec` has been replaced by `QStringConverter`, so there's no surprise that the `setCodec` member function was removed from  `QTextStream`. Instead, I can see there a member function `setEncoding`, which seems to be the needed replacement. Go and try it yourself - I've never used this part of Qt.

Comment: Thank you, you are amazing, that was it : )